# Prevent URL's parameter can't be null in UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

Working on angular single page application.
I am trying this...

```
.state('one-category-product-list', {
        url: '/products/:category/:category_id',
        views: {
            '': {
                templateUrl: './view/single-category-product.html',
                controller: 'ProductsController'
            },
            nav:{
                templateUrl: function() {
                    if (authenticate() == 'customer') {
                        return './view/template/nav-login.html';
                    }
                    return './view/template/nav.html';
                }
            },
            footer:{
                templateUrl: './view/template/footer.html'
            }
        }
    })
```

the issue with me if a user will not pass the category_id there or directly enters the URL without last parameter like ***www.example.com/product/category/*** then it takes parameters category_id: "". How to restrict this.

Comment: So you want to prevent the state change ?

Comment: yeah, or it will be redirected to otherwise state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
.state('one-category-product-list', {
    url: '/products/:category/:category_id',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: './view/single-category-product.html',
            controller: 'ProductsController'
        },
        nav: {
            templateUrl: function () {
                if (authenticate() == 'customer') {
                    return './view/template/nav-login.html';
                }
                return './view/template/nav.html';
            }
        },
        footer: {
            templateUrl: './view/template/footer.html'
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        data:($stateParams,$state, $q) => {
            if(!$stateParams.category_id) {
                $state.go('my-otherwise-state');
                return $q.reject('No state params');
            }

        }
    }
})
```